# How to use Bluetooth headset with Raspberry Bi (Raspbian)?

Tags: linux, audio, bluetooth, headset

Yesterday I spent almost the entire day trying to get something working I expected to be straightforward: getting a Bluetooth headset working with Linux.

I know that there is bluez as the Linux Bluetooth stack - the official sources for Raspbian contain version 4.99 which should have support for A2DP, HFP and HSP. The newer versions 5.xx have dropped support for HFP and HSP as far as I know (for whatever reason).

What I did was install bluez from the official sources and pair the headset. I added an `/etc/asound.conf` file:

```
pcm.btheadset {
    type plug
       slave {
           pcm {
               type bluetooth
               device XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX 
               profile "auto"
           }   
       }   
       hint {
           show on
           description "BT Headset"
       }   
    }
    ctl.btheadset {
      type bluetooth
    }
}
```

Then I can output audio with `aplay -D btheadset -f S16_LE < /etc/kernel.img`.

I tried to get audio input working the same way, by doing `arecord -D btheadset /tmp/test.wav` but it does not record anything.

I guess that only A2DP is working but not HSP/HFP. I did a lot of Googling but it seems that Bluetooth headsets are not really well supported under Linux. This really surprises me - is really no one using this?

I am even thinking about reading into Bluetooth programming - any ideas where to start?

Also, I wonder because the headset is working fine with Android which - as far as I know uses bluez 5.xx as well. Any thoughts on that?

Thanks for every hint you can give me.